# How to do a meta-analysis of studies that used permutation test

Tags: nonparametric, meta-analysis, ordinal-data, permutation-test

I would like to combine results of multiple studies, that used permutation test (or sometimes called randomization test) to obtain their p-values. The dependent variable is shuffled many times, within exchangeability blocks, to obtain null-distribution of a specific test statistic.

Furthermore, the test statistic they used, is based on ranks (e.g. U, AUC, proportional odds, but I can transform one into another).

How can I combine these studies to obtain overall p-value?
How can I combine these studies to get effect size, with some kind of confindence interval around it?

Edit: I do have access to the raw data, but I have to use rank-based measures and permutation test.

Comment: If you have the underlying data why not re-analyse it using the same method for each study and get an effect size and standard error from each? Or do I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: The problem is then how to get standard errors using permutation test. I still want to take into an account that the results came from different studies. I would still call this a meta-analysis, although I might be mistaken.